# Read data from firebase with React Hooks into array

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I am tring to read from `firebase` a date that should be placed in an `array`. A calendar has been implemented and it retrieves the data from the `array`. The layout of the `array` looks like const events. However, this data is static and I want to change that by extracting the data from `firebase`.

The moment the page is loaded, the database will be read out by using `useEffect`, if I then `console.log(state);` I get to see the value of `firebase` with a few seconds of delay. However, when I try to add it to the `state` by means of `React hooks`, it continues to execute the `useEffect()` function (see image from console.log). At the moment there is only 1 `object` in `firebase`, but of course there will be more.

Actually the moment the page is loaded the events should be read in from `firebase`. These can be found in `firebase under / events`, then these events must be added to the eventDb array that will be reloaded later in `<Calendar events = {eventDb}`.

Is it possible to realize this? and what am I doing wrong which keeps it using the `useEffect` function?

I am discovering React and this is one of the things I would like to learn.

The code:

```
import React , {useEffect} from "react";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import styles from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/views/dashboardStyle.js";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Col } from "react-bootstrap";

import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css'
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer, Views } from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment';
import Firebase from 'firebase';

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

function rand() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 20) - 10;
}

function getModalStyle() {
  const top = 50 + rand();
  const left = 50 + rand();

  return {
    top: `${top}%`,
    left: `${left}%`,
    transform: `translate(-${top}%, -${left}%)`,
  };
}

const events = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'Board meeting',
      start: new Date(2020, 1, 10, 9, 0, 0),
      end: new Date(2020, 1, 10, 9, 15, 0),
      resourceId: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'MS training',
      desc: 'this is a test',
      start: new Date(2020, 1, 10, 9, 0, 0),
      end: new Date(2020, 1, 10, 9, 15, 0),
      resourceId: 2,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'MS training',

      start: new Date(2020, 1, 10, 9, 10, 0),
      end: new Date(2020, 1, 10, 9, 25, 0),
      resourceId: 2,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Team lead meeting',
      start: new Date(2018, 0, 29, 8, 30, 0),
      end: new Date(2018, 0, 29, 12, 30, 0),
      resourceId: 3,
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: new Date(2018, 0, 30, 7, 0, 0),
      end: new Date(2018, 0, 30, 10, 30, 0),
      resourceId: 4,
    },
  ]

export default function CalendarDesk() {
    const [eventDb, setEventDb] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let ref = Firebase.database().ref('/events');
        ref.on('value' , snapshot => {
            var state = snapshot.val();
            setEventDb([...eventDb,{
                title: state.title,id: state.id,resourceId: state.resourceId,start: state.start,end: state.end
            }]);
        });

    } );
console.log(eventDb);

  const service = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Knippen',
        price: 11.53,
        time: 10.00,
        amount: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Scheren',
        price: 10.82,
        time: 10.00,
        amount: 1
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Wassen',
        price: 12.66,
        time: 10.00,
        amount: 1
  }]

      const resourceMap = [
        { resourceId: 1, resourceTitle: 'Robin Frissen' },
        { resourceId: 2, resourceTitle: 'Raoul Frissen' },
        { resourceId: 3, resourceTitle: 'Joppe Meijers' },
      ]

      let today = new Date();

  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
          <h3>Agenda</h3>
          <Row >
            <Col md={12} >          
                <Calendar
                events={eventDb}
                localizer={localizer}
                defaultView={'day'}
                views ={['day', 'work_week']}
                step={5}
                defaultDate={new Date()}
                min={new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 8)}
                max={new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 18)}
                resources={resourceMap}
                resourceIdAccessor="resourceId"
                resourceTitleAccessor="resourceTitle"
                />
            </Col>
        </Row>
        </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The console.log:]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

When it's written this way `useEffect(() => {})` it always runs whenever the component re renders.

When it's written this way `useEffect(() => {}, [])` it runs only once because there is no dependency. In this situation, it acts like a `componentDidMount` as it has no dependency so it only runs when the component is mounted.

When it's written this way `useEffect(() => {console.log(variable)}, [variable])` it will only run on first mount and then when the variable changes. if the variable does not change, the function will not run even if a re-render occurs.

You can read more at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html